# Parse document in background after upload in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a simple Flask application to parse a csv file. I would like the file to be parsed in the background so the user doesn't have to wait. I've explored threading and multiprocessing, however I'm unsure what the best option is.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            location = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(location)
            parser = Parser(location)
            thread = Thread(target=parser.read_csv())
            thread.daemon = True
            thread.start()
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file'))
    return render_template('index.html')
```

How can I build this in such a way that:

- The user uploads the file
- The user is redirected to another page while the csv is being parsed in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for recognizing that a webpage should offer sub-second response time,
even if processing the .csv might take longer than that.

You have the background thread processing happening already.
You could fork a child if you want greater isolation.

You could immediately offer a page with a link to results,
and hope the human offers you a long enough interactive delay
that processing is finished by then.
Or immediately 302 redirect to such a page.

Or have the results page estimate (from .csv file size)
when processing will be finished, and display *that* as a "sorry, you lose"
page that invites clicking in a minute when it should be ready.
Even without a sensible estimate you could just hardcode ten-second retries.

The page could auto-refresh, polling until processing is complete.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh.
You could adaptively reduce `n = 5; meta = f'content="{n}; url=/results"'`
so that `n` gets smaller as the result file nears its final length.

An async technique like websockets or long-poll would let your
server notify the browser exactly when the parsed result is available,
but that sounds like overkill for the current use case.